# Make new line in window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, line, space, onbeforeunload

I was looking and was not able to find out how to make a new line in the window.onbeforeunload in Javascript, can any help me out? I am sorry if this have already been posted, but have been looking for some time now and found nothing.

Comment: Hit the enter key on your keyboard? Otherwise, I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\n`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {  
    return "I have\nNewlines!";
}
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/8nBLD/) (right click the `Output` pane and select > `Reload Frame`)

Comment: or just refresh the page ;)